# Exclamatory questions and punctuation order

Tags: punctuation

What is the punctuation order of question marks and exclamation points in exclamatory questions, e.g. *How easy was that*?

It could be *How easy was that!?*, or *How easy was that?!*

Are there any prescriptive rules for this(!?|?!) Or should I just do whatever I want?

Comment: I _think_ that whichever you want the most emphasis on comes first. But it'd be great if the [interrobang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrobang) were more accepted.

Comment: @VampDuc I approve! Why isn't this punctuation mark accepted‽

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Indeed you have found a good duplicate target! I was unable to find it when searching preliminarily. Nice find!